# Rails app in subdirectory in production not redirecting properly to install shopify store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify, shopify-app

Using localhost:3000 I was able to install the shopify store and interact with it. However, when deploying it into production, which is in a subdirectory (www.website.com/app_name), the "login" for the shop is redirected to root and not to the subdirectory. I whitelisted the redirect urls in the shopify app dashboard.

In omniauth.rb

```
callback_url: "http://{domain}/{app_name}/auth/shopify/callback"
```

In routes.rb

```
mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/{app_name}'
```

Apart from the code above, the settings for shopify are the ones that the generator created. Any ideas in how to fix this?

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I did that pattern I had to set the prefix for OmniAuth... in my old config.ru that works for this.. see..

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  # allow us to connect this App via the /fooblefuzz route instead of just 
  the root of the heroku app URL /
  configure do |config|
      config.path_prefix = '/fooblefuzz/auth'
  end
```

So this code works as https://www.example.com/fooblefuzz/auth/shopify/callback

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your answer. I tried putting it in omniauth.rb, it has the same result.